# What part of chrome/firefox code needs to be tweaked after which browser tries to resolve names with spaces in between?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

If I have a nameserver which support names with spaces in between, what part of chrome/firefox code needs to be tweaked after which browser tries to resolve names with spaces in between. Currently any string with spaces in between is treated as search query and directly given to search engine.
https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/omnibox this links states that any term with spaces is treated as search query.

Current internet architecture does not allow dns names with space (as pointed out by martin). I am experimenting for a new age architecture in which names with spaces could be supported.

Comment: If you actually have [a nameserver](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains/Domains-Explained/what-is-a-nameserver-261/) this has nothing to do with the browser.

Comment: You will need to clarify: 1) What you mean by nameserver in your case? 2) what you mean by `chrome/firefox code`, is in do you want to make your own custom browser? 3) If so, have you tried looking at the respective Browsers App store? 4) If you are trying to find a domain name containing a space, while this can be technically possible, you should [read this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/342284/does-active-directory-support-dns-names-with-spaces) about why this will not work the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks martin for bringing out these pointers. I am actually hosting a nameserver which could support names with spaces . But currently even after changing the nameserver on my local machine i was unable to navigate to a url like "my page" since chrome/firefox assumes any phrases with spaces as search query and the gives search engine results without trying to resolve with local name server.

Comment: Read the post I linked, that will tell you why. The issue is not with any browser or browser provider. It's simply not the way the internet is intended to work.

Comment: Answering to your questions 1) I have a custom nameserver, which could support names with spaces example : $nslookup <string with phrases> could be resolved. 2) From my understanding through extensions i could not make os level calls like lookup of hostname, so i want to to tweak the part of code which distinguishes hostname and search query. 3) I could not find any extension which does the same in appstore 4)RFC does not allow names with spaces, but i am more interested in is it posssible to  make a hostnamelookup call with spaces in between.

Comment: @martin I am actually trying out this experiment for new internet architecture in a way.Thanks a lot for your pointers.

Comment: If my answer below doesn't give you a solution (albeit not the one you wanted!) or otherwise misses your point, I would suggest you **edit** your question to add your comments into the main question and make the question more exact. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> I am actually hosting a nameserver which could support names with spaces . But currently even after changing the nameserver on my local machine i was unable to navigate to a url like "my page" since chrome/firefox assumes any phrases with spaces as search query and the gives search engine results without trying to resolve with local name server.

In answer to the clarification provided; [this post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/342284/does-active-directory-support-dns-names-with-spaces) goes over exactly this issue:

> A *domain name* can include any binary octet in the range 0 to 255.
>
> However if your AD entries represent *host names*, then a space is not a valid character.  A host name (i.e. a domain name that points to an `A` or `AAAA` record) must follow the rules from [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123), which essentially restricts the legal characters to LDH ("letter digit hyphen").

-- Answer by Alnitak [here](https://serverfault.com/a/342303/278183).

This clarifies that the issue you present is not an issue with any browser or browser provider. It's simply not the way the internet is intended to work.

> So, the Active Directory's DNS does not lack support for spaces in DNS names as a shortcoing but because it follows the same rules as everyone else.

**See also:**

- RFC 952 [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952)
- RFC 1035 [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035)
- RRC 2181 [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181)

**Finally**

To truly answer your question; you would need to explore Chrome and Firefox developer forums and similar places to see if they give clues as to what part of the code you'd need to explore if you really want to force through the shape of domain names you're trying to allow. I think chrome is Proprietory (not sure) and Firefox is *probably* proprietory (again, not sure but easy for you to explore).